# Is there a golang redis client that auto detects new shards for pubsub?

Tags: go, redis, publish-subscribe, sharding, redis-cluster

[UPDATE]: Current redis sends every published message to every node in entire cluster:

```
/* -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * CLUSTER Pub/Sub support
 *
 * For now we do very little, just propagating PUBLISH messages across the whole
 * cluster. In the future we'll try to get smarter and avoiding propagating those
 * messages to hosts without receives for a given channel.
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
void clusterPropagatePublish(robj *channel, robj *message) {
    clusterSendPublish(NULL, channel, message);
}
```

This is original text of question, which is not correct:

> As I understand it I need to:
>
> 1. Given a channel, find the the node that owns the hash slot.
> 2. Subscribe to that node and also to cluster:slots to detect migrations.
> 3. Upon slot migration, subscribe to the channel on the new node and keep the old connection open.
> 4. Forward messages to the application from the old connection until it closes and remember those messages.
> 5. When migration is complete and the old connection closed, forward messages from the new connection, trimming the remembered messages
>      from the first connection.
>
> Do any of the golang redis client library do this? I’ve looked through
>   many and it feels like I need to write this logic myself, constantly
>   polling `CLUSTER SLOTS` or listening to a pubsub of that info to know
>   when shards increase or decrease and move my existing pubsub
>   scriptions from one server to another.
>
> I.e. there lots of golang libs that handle normal GET key with cluster
>   even if the number of shards changes. But pubsub and cluster is a
>   whole other thing right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PubSub channels in the Redis cluster are shared among all nodes - messages are passed via the internal bus so you don't need a special client and/or logic.

> In a Redis Cluster clients can subscribe to every node, and can also publish to every other node. The cluster will make sure that published messages are forwarded as needed.

Source: [Redis Cluster Specification](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec)

Comment: So if I’m listening to channel ABC123 on node1 of a 3 node system, and we increase the number of nodes to 17, channel ABC123 will still be on that same machine and the original TCP connection will not break from the event of new nodes being added?

Comment: So if I have 1000 connected TCP subscribers to 1000 different channels, and we increase the number of nodes and slots dramatically, over and over, is there now a bunch of over-head of mapping these old subscribers vs. if we were to shut them all down, reboot with the final number of slots, and have them connect fresh?

Comment: Theoretically it should work, but practically I'd test it before believing anything someone writes on SO ;)

Comment: Ok I see you are correct sir! Thank you very much. I finally found the exact line of c code in cluster.c with the comment: “CLUSTER Pub/Sub support
 *
 * For now we do very little, just propagating PUBLISH messages across the whole
 * cluster. In the future we'll try to get smarter and avoiding propagating those
 * messages to hosts without receives for a given channel.“

Comment: Great - nothing beats deep-diving into the (open) source code :) Please let us know (preferably via the GitHub repo of the project) if you encounter any difficulties with this (so we can learn and prioritize future version accurately).